# Search by specific cloumn name in Seam

Tags: jsf, seam, crud

I am working in seam with jsf1.2.

Everything working fine for me, except the search operation. Can anyone please suggest me to go in a right way?

Here, how I am having my form:

```
            <h:form class="input-list" id="searchUser" style="width:100%;"
            name="searchUser">
                    <div class="edit-label">FIRST NAME :</div>
                <h:inputText tabindex="1" id="firstName" type="text" class="miniusername clp"
                value="#{userListAction.firstName}" required="true">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="20" />
            </h:inputText>

            <h:commandButton value="Search" tabindex="2" style="margin-left: 5px"
                action="#{userListAction.retrieveName}" class="usersearch">
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

My interface:

```
    @Local
    public interface UserListAction extends Serializable {

        public List<User> retrieveCustomers();

        public List<User> retrieveEmployees();

        public List<User> getUsersList();

        public CLRPUser getLoginUser();

        public List<User> retrieveName();

        @WebRemote
        public String deleteById(Integer userId);

        @WebRemote
        public CLRPUser getUserById(Integer userId);

        public UserTypeEnum getUserType();

        public void setUserType(UserTypeEnum userType);

        public void setFirstName(String firstName);

        public String getFirstName();

        public CLRPUser getCurrentUser();

        public void setCurrentUser(CLRPUser currentUser);

    }
```

Action class which implements the interface:

```
    @Name("userListAction")
    @Stateless
    @AutoCreate
    public class UserListActionImpl implements UserListAction {

        @In
        protected UserService userService;

        @Out(value = "userType", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        private UserTypeEnum userType;

        @In
        private LoggedInUser loggedInUser;

        @Out(value = "currentUser", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        @In(value = "currentUser", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        private CLRPUser currentUser;   

        @In(value = "firstName", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        private String firstName;

        /**
         * 
         */

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8649412602585430272L;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see com.ermms.clrp.user.UserAction#getUsersList()
         */


        public List<User> retrieveName() {
            System.out.print("FirstName is :" + firstName);
            return userService.getAllUsers(firstName);
        }


        public UserTypeEnum getUserType() {
            return this.userType;
        }

        public void setUserType(UserTypeEnum userType) {
            this.userType = userType;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        @Override
        public CLRPUser getCurrentUser() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setCurrentUser(CLRPUser currentUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Console says the  First name is : null.

I tried more times, but lost my mind in this. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you inject the `firstName` in the `userListAction`-component? Where should this come from?
If there is nothing more, I guess it works as follows:

1. user enters first name and clicks the command button
2. the form gets submitted and the entered first name is set into the model using the setter-method
3. when executing the command button-action Seam-bijection takes place and injects the value for the `firstName` stored in "some" context. Since it is not defined anywhere, `null` is injected.

So if you need the injection (for any case), you should put the correct value in the contest at any place. If not, just remove the `@In` annotation.

Comment: What MrD is trying to tell you is that you don't need to inject every field in the form. Your inputtext value will be wired to firstName property of your UseListAction bean when the form is submitted.

Comment: Wow... Great. It works like charm. Thank you MrD and Esteve.. Also apologies for my delay.. I have tied with other project.. Hats off to you MrD.